# Show totals in last row of query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to show the totals of the last 2 columns but can't seam to get the right code.
Here is the code.

```
 declare @FromDate as datetime
 declare @ToDate as datetime
 set @FromDate='1/1/2018'
 set @ToDate='1/31/2018'

Select
 OrderMain.OrderNumber,
 OrderMain.OrderDate,       
 OrderMain.TotalMiles,
 OFAddStop.FeeValue AS NumberStops

From 
 Ordermain with (readuncommitted)
 Left Outer Join Customer with (readuncommitted) on Ordermain.CustomerID=Customer.CustomerID
 Left outer join OrderFee OFAddStop with (readuncommitted) on OFAddStop.OrderID=OrderMain.OrderID 
   and OFAddStop.Sequence=9 and OFAddStop.SubSequence=6

Where
 Customer.CustomerCode IN('36716')
 and OrderMain.OrderDate >=@FromDate
 and OrderMain.OrderDate <=@ToDate
 and OrderMain.OrderStatus in ('N','A','I','P')
```

Here is an example of the Query

```
 OrderNumber   OrderDate    TotalMiles NumberStops 
  10747511     01/02/18        280        6 
  10750287     01/03/18        118        4
```

The last row should look like this

```
 OrderNumber   OrderDate    TotalMiles NumberStops 
  10747511     01/02/18        280        6 
  10750287     01/03/18        118        4    
 Total                         398        10
```

Can someone show me the correct way to make this happen?

Comment: Your code sure doesn't look like MySQL.  Can you tag your question correctly?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can do this using [`GROUPING SETS`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx), but you need an aggregation query:

```
Select om.OrderNumber, om.OrderDate,
       SUM(om.TotalMiles) as TotalMiles,
       SUM(oaf.FeeValue) as NumberStops
From Ordermain om Join
     Customer c
     on om.CustomerID = c.CustomerID Left outer join
     OrderFee oaf
     on oaf.OrderID = om.OrderID and
        oaf.Sequence = 9 and oaf.SubSequence = 6
Where c.CustomerCode in ('36716') and
      om.OrderDate >= @FromDate
      om.OrderDate <= @ToDate and
      om.OrderStatus in ('P', 'A', 'I', 'N')  -- couldn't resist
group by grouping sets ( (om.OrderNumber, om.OrderDate), () );
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The aggregation is on the first two columns.  I presume there are no duplicates for those.
- You are looking for a specific customer, so the `join` to that table should be a regular `join`.

Answer (score 1):

If the db accepts `With` clause.

```
 declare @FromDate as datetime
 declare @ToDate as datetime
 set @FromDate='1/1/2018'
 set @ToDate='1/31/2018'

 With
 records as (
   Select
     cast(OrderMain.OrderNumber as varchar(32)) OrderNumber,
     OrderMain.OrderDate,       
     OrderMain.TotalMiles,
     OFAddStop.FeeValue AS NumberStops
   From 
     Ordermain with (readuncommitted)
     Left Outer Join Customer with (readuncommitted) on 
       Ordermain.CustomerID=Customer.CustomerID
     Left outer join OrderFee OFAddStop with (readuncommitted) on 
       OFAddStop.OrderID=OrderMain.OrderID 
       and OFAddStop.Sequence=9 and OFAddStop.SubSequence=6
    Where
      Customer.CustomerCode IN('36716')
      and OrderMain.OrderDate >=@FromDate
      and OrderMain.OrderDate <=@ToDate
      and OrderMain.OrderStatus in ('N','A','I','P')
  )
  Select
     OrderNumber,
     OrderDate,
     TotalMiles,
     NumberStops
  From
     records
  Union All
  Select
    'Total',
    null,
    sum(TotalMiles),
    sum(NumberStops)
  From
     records
```